# Command to open new console with ruby script after running selenium server

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.1, console, selenium-rc, rails-console

I am trying to run a script consisting of different commands which are :

1) system "bundle exec rails s -e test -d"

2) system "bundle exec selenium-rc"

3) system "bundle exec rspec test/selenium/*_sel.rb"

now when line 1 executes server runs and console's control is transferred back. But After execution of line no 2 selenium server runs but console's control is not transfered back due to which line no 3 is not executed.

So my question is how we can run all three command concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by some research instead of line 2 now I am using following code to run selenium server

```
require 'selenium/rake/tasks'
JAR_FILE_PATTERN = "vendor/selenium-remote-control/selenium-server-*.jar"    
@port = 4444      
@jar_file = "YOUR_PROJECT_PATH/vendor/selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar"   
@background = true   
@timeout_in_seconds = 3 * 60   
@wait_until_up_and_running = true  
@additional_args = []  
@additional_args << "-singleWindow"   

raise "Could not find jar file '#{@jar_file}'. Expected it under     #{JAR_FILE_PATTERN}"      unless @jar_file && File.exists?(@jar_file)    
remote_control = Selenium::RemoteControl::RemoteControl.new("0.0.0.0", @port, :timeout => @timeout_in_seconds)   
remote_control.jar_file = @jar_file    
remote_control.additional_args = @additional_args   
remote_control.log_to = @log_to   
remote_control.start :background => true       
if @background && @wait_until_up_and_running       
  TCPSocket.wait_for_service :host => @host, :port => @port     
end
```

3)  # now line no 3 comes here

4)  remote_control.stop # this line stops there server